# vim - open file and goto line number using <filename>:<line nbr>:

Tags: vim, gvim

Several tools such as `grep`, `py.test`, etc ... use the pattern `<FileName>:<line number>:` to point to errors.  For example:

```
; grep -Hn Common setup.cfg
setup.cfg:11:    Common
```

How can I modify vim and gvim so that I can invoke them like so:

```
gvim setup.cfg:11:
```

instead of

```
gvim setup.cfg +11
```

I know that I can write a small shell script that would parse things but I wonder if there is an easier way.

Comment: This isn't exactly analogous, but vim does have a feature to load the output from grep or (for example) compiler errors from make, and navigate between them. See `:help quickfix` for more info.

Comment: [better-gf](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/vim-bettergf) is for the similar use case of needing to do `gf` on a (possibly relative, possibly including line and column number) reference to a file, whether in an embedded terminal or in any kind of buffer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the file:line plugin available [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2184), which does exactly what you want...

Comment: It sure does and with the added bonus that you can use [vundle](https://github.com/vim-scripts/vundle) to install it.

Comment: The references [file-line](https://github.com/bogado/file-line) plugin has some issues, including brokeness when tab pages are in use. [vim-fetch](https://github.com/kopischke/vim-fetch) does what file-line does, but better.

Answer (score 9):

There isn't a way, and I think a script is the only way. 
The reason being, what if you had a file called setup.cfg:11 and wanted to edit it?

Here is a quick script that does what you want as a oneliner...

```
editline() { vim ${1%%:*} +${1##*:}; }
```

Comment: Sorry this is not accurate:  What if you had a file called `+11`?  You can, of course, use `--` for that.

Comment: You can edit a +11 file by saying vim ./+11

Answer (score 3):

With [Vundle.vim](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim), add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
Plugin 'bogado/file-line'
```

Comment: @Sardathrion: Which issues do you have?

Comment: I moved to neovim and there are lots of issues that mark other modules (or whatever neovim calls them) as incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use such alias:

```
alias gd 'set number=`echo \!:1 | perl -pe "s/([0-9]*:)?(.+)[,:]([0-9]+).*/\3/"`; set file=`echo \!:1 | perl -pe "s/([0-9]*:)?(.+)[,:]([0-9]+).*/\2/"`; eval "if ($number == $file) then \\
   gvim $file \\
else \\
   gvim $file +$number \\
endif"'
```